# generating proc-macro-expanded version of code at build time?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-macros

I have two crates, `foo` and `foo_macros`, the latter of which contains some proc macros. I'd like, when building `foo`, to generate a version of the source tree in which the proc macros from `foo_macros` are expanded. How should I approach this / is there prior art / to what extent is this even possible?

I'm aware of `cargo-expand` (https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand), but it doesn't advertise any build system integration.

Some nice-to-have functionality would be

- I can check the generated code into git, so that it can be browsed on github (I don't need help with this one, it's just to clarify intent).
- macros from std and other libs are not (or maybe, optionally) expanded. The intent is to aid in documenting/developing/debugging the proc macros of the `foo` project, expanding `vec!` and `println!` doesn't help with that.
- the generated code compiles, at least enough that I can navigate it with my editor's LSP functionality
- the generated code compiles, and I can manually tweak/iterate on it to help figure out what changes to make to the upstream macros.
- the generated code compiles, and I can arrange to have some cfg flag in `foo` that toggles between using the original vs macro-expanded source files.

(I see the disclaimer in `cargo-expand` (https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand#disclaimer), so I realize "the generated code compiles" will at best come with caveats).

Comment: Why do you want that? This is not generally possible (see my answer on your other question). If this is just for debugging the macros, your can use `cargo expand` or rust-analyzer "Expand macro recursively" when needed.

Comment: at a minimum, `cargo expand` and rust analyzer aren't available when viewing code on github

Comment: This kinda sounds like you just want code generation via a `build.rs` script. But answering *Why do you want that?* would help clarify.

Comment: Sounds very suspiciously like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).